# How to create a detailed-list view for Android 4.0 tablet, exactly like Contacts App?

Tags: android, list, layout, contacts, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm actually developing a **tablet** application for **Android 4.0**, and I need to use a layout displaying 2 or 3 panes (just like the default **Contacts** app).
It will display a catalog of products:

1. The first pane is a list of items
2. The second pane is the detailled view of the currently selected item in the list
3. The last pane is optional, showing a wish list (it can be showed or hidden)

### The approach

So, I'm currently using a `ListFragment` for the list pane, and a simple `Fragment` for the details pane. The last one isn't actually integrated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.###.###.ui.fragments.ListFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailsFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.###.###.ui.fragments.DetailsFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

- Is there a better approach for this design ?

### The style

I also want to follow the Android 4.0 Design Guidelines and apply to my app the same design as the default Contacts App. I searched for a tutorial on how to apply this *style*, and I can't find anything about that.

[Here's an exact picture of what I need.](http://developer.android.com/design/media/multipane_view_tablet.png) (Sorry, I'm not yet allowed to post images...)

- How can I implement the default Android 4.0 detailled-list style ?

I've seen [this resource picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXBo7.png) on the Guidelines webpage. I'm sure there is a simple way to implement this style on any application... So, if anyone can help me doing this...

Comment: Looks good. You might need to change the weights to "7" and "10" but I could be wrong.

Comment: That's the same method, i'm just using 0.3 (could be 3 or 30) and 0.7 (could be 7 or 70). Using "7" and "10" makes the list view look larger.